# Loop over array and show the appropriate div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have an array of classes which are returned to me from a database. Something like:

```
var styleClasses = ["ClassA", "ClassB", "ClassC", "ClassD"];
```

I have a a page where the markup is something like:

```
<div class="main-details">
            <div class="ClassA" style="display:none;">
                <div class="Inner-Details">

                </div>
                <div class="Inner-Details">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ClassB" style="display:none;">
                <div class="Inner-Details">

                </div>
                <div class="Inner-Details">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ClassC" style="display:none;">
                <div class="Inner-Details">

                </div>
                <div class="Inner-Details">

                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

What I am trying to achieve is, whatever class is in my array I want the appropriate div to be displayed. I can loop over the array and get the value using `.each` function but I don't know how to match that with the div class and show it accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the jQuery function [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) on the classes at each iteration of your `.each()`.

```
var styleClasses = ["ClassA", "ClassB", "ClassC", "ClassD"];

$(styleClasses).each(function(){
    $('.'+this).show(); // does this:  $('.classA').show();
});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/v6667yag/1/)

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

```
var styleClasses = ["ClassA", "ClassB", "ClassC", "ClassD"];
styleClasses.forEach(function(class){
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName(class),function(el){
       el.style.display="block";
    });
});
```

Iterate over the classes and then over each element in that class and add the style.

Comment: What is `class` which is passed to the `function`? Will that be my div classes?

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function(){
  var styleClasses = ["ClassA", "ClassB", "ClassC", "ClassD"];

  for (var i = 0; i < styleClasses.length; i++) {
     $('.'+styleClasses[i]).show();
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-details">
            <div class="ClassA" style="display:none;">
                <div class="Inner-Details">
ClassA
                </div>
                <div class="Inner-Details">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ClassB" style="display:none;">
                <div class="Inner-Details">
ClassB
                </div>
                <div class="Inner-Details">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ClassC" style="display:none;">
                <div class="Inner-Details">
ClassC
                </div>
                <div class="Inner-Details">

                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems to work for me, though you should execute your code after the document is completly loaded  (in a $(document.ready(function(){/* your code here */}); )

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: @Code Welcome :-)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var styleClasses = ["ClassA", "ClassB", "ClassC", "ClassD"];
for (var i = 0; i < styleClasses.length; i++) {


  $('.' + styleClasses[i]).show()
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-details">
  <div class="ClassA" style="display:none;">1
    <div class="Inner-Details">

    </div>
    <div class="Inner-Details">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ClassB" style="display:none;">2
    <div class="Inner-Details">

    </div>
    <div class="Inner-Details">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ClassC" style="display:none;">3
    <div class="Inner-Details">

    </div>
    <div class="Inner-Details">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

1. Loop the array and use it value as selector.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: @Code happy coding